# Custom formula loader for assetic

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

I have searched high and low and could not find any example on how to write custom formula loader for assetic. Basically, I want to add a twig function (if possible, or do I have to use tag?) named add_asset. I need to somehow let assetic know that it must parse this function inside twig templates to gather assets to dump.

I have a hint that it has something to do with the AsseticTokenParser and TwigFormulaLoader but so far I have not figured that out yet. I have spent the whole weekend looking at this code and still have not figured out anything useful so far. Any direction is much appreciated.

This is a part of the quest to delay loading and processing assets till the very end of the response processing on Symfony 2.

I also posted a question on [Dynamically adding assets via php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470636/dynamically-add-assets-via-php) which is also related to this question (but that one is for rendering assets, this one is for dumping assets)

Comment: After reading both of your questions, it doesn't seem to make sense. If I understand, you want to dynamically create css and js file for each request. That would create a mess with the potential of overwriting css and js files that are being used. However if you want dynamically choice which css and js files are used then there is no need to use assetic.

Comment: not really, asset files are already dumped and processed. What we simply want to do is to wait till the last minute to decide which css/js files to include and where to place them (these files are supposed to be already filtered and processed by assetic dump).

Comment: Actually, your comment made me think. It turned out that you are right, it's impossible for me to dump the asstic files via console because the way the asset files are added. Since I need to wait till the end of everything to know the list of files I need to process there is no way i can use assetic dump (unless I don't want to use the combine feature, which I do). So anyhow, I got around it be doing the "dumping" on each request if and only if cache file is not available.

Comment: Can you please explain what _the last minute_ mean?

Comment: By that I meant I need to wait until the the page content finishes loading (when it reaches the body end tag (right now I'm hooking to Symfony onResponse event)). The reason is that our framework allows 3rd party to use plugins to inject elements/content and we need a way to scan and remove duplicated asset files requested by 3rd party plugins, and we also need a way to decide the best asset version to load (for example, should we load jquery 1.7 or the latest?).

Comment: I finally have working code, for those interested please refer to https://github.com/Nilead/NileadAsseticBundle/